# Повторное использование  admob publisher_id

Tags: admob, android

Доброго времени суток.
При генерации publisher_id admob запрашивает имя пакета, но реклама приходит и в других приложениях с этим publisher_id.
Можно ли использовать один publisher_id  для нескольких приложений?

Comment: 1) Не рекомендуется.
2) Зачем?

Comment: я тоже так думаю, вопрос  от заказчика, много однотипных приложений, и не хочется каждый раз новый генерировать )

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я в курсе, адмоб данное действие даже запрещает. Поищите в справке адмоба. Один пакайдж наме один ид. итд.

Answer (score 0):

На практике можно, работать будет. Но адмоб требует генерировать разные даже банеры. Так написано в документации